# Enums in AS3 / Flash / Flex?

Tags: actionscript-3, enums

One thing I really like about AS3 over AS2 is how much more compile-time type-checking it adds. However, it seems to be somewhat lacking in that there is no type-checked enumeration structure available. What's a good (best / accepted) way to do custom enumerated types in AS3?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

your answer after the jump :-)

[Enumerations with classes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f2f.html)

Comment: while my edit is being reviewed I think this link would be similar to the one originally provided: [Enumerations with classes](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f2f.html)

Answer (score 15):

Just wanted to share [my way](http://www.liranuna.com/typesafe-assignable-enumerations-in-as3/)

Comment: A bit verbose, but I like it.

Answer (score 1):

I know, this is a little outdated and does not exactly answer your question, but you might wanna check out [Haxe](https://haxe.org). You can also use it to generate AS3 for you, plus there are many other reasons to use it. But this'd really get off topic...

Answer (score 1):

I recently discovered that [as3commons library](http://www.as3commons.org) has a good base helper class [Enum](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-lang/asdoc/org/as3commons/lang/Enum.html) for enums implemetation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to be a **true** enum it needs to both:

- Enforce type safety
- Prevent rogue instances

Few of the simple solutions do both, and the base classes that do are overly complex IMO.

My current favourite is the following style - safe and simple, and shouldn't confuse anyone:

```
public final class FruitEnum {
    private static const CREATE:Object = {};

    public static const APPLE:FruitEnum = new FruitEnum(CREATE);
    public static const ORANGE:FruitEnum = new FruitEnum(CREATE);
    public static const BANANA:FruitEnum = new FruitEnum(CREATE);

    public function FruitEnum(permission:Object) {
        if (permission !== CREATE){
            throw new Error("Enum cannot be instantiated from outside");
        }
    }
}
```

CAVEAT: I have seen rare circumstances where a variable initialisation reads an enum const *before* it set, but in those cases the problem applied equally to other const-based enum emulations.